# Delete 'bad stuff' from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Our company has very strict guidelines in what technologies our employees are allowed to program. Because of that, I'm looking now for a way to delete 'bad stuff' from all Visual Studio installations on every development machine (similiar to group and machine restrictions that can be configured in a Active Directory domain environment).

This includes:

1. Everything related to Visual Basic
2. Everything related to Windows Forms
3. Default WPF templates (as we want to enforce our employees to strictly use MVVM)

I know Visual Studio has certain folders for "Project Templates", "Item Templates", but they're cluttered everywhere (for each framework version, language, .NET syntax) and even if the templates are gone, one can still use e.g. Windows Forms components through the .NET framework (Windows.Forms namespace)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: VB.NET is "bad stuff"? Sounds like ignorance.

Comment: can't you go to tools > extensions and updates and uninstall / disable stuff there ? 
Alternatively tell them to use MVVM

Comment: @JohnSaunders No, VB.NET is not bad. VB.NET is just another CLI language, but our employees should strictly code in C#.

Comment: @Chris I was hoping for a more automated mechanism as I'll have to do it on 40 machines.

Comment: mass email saying if you don't use MVVM you are fired ? :p

Comment: Suggestion: let your employees code in what they decide is best. Then, don't let VB.NET code pass code review. You may find that you will have reasons to create a small amount of VB.NET code (like to take advantage of XML literal support).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not in charge of the review process, also I'm not the one who decided VB.NET is bad.

Comment: If you are using source control you may be able to make a policy over what can be checked in. Have not really looked into this but it could be possible

Comment: True. But you can tell them I say they're wrong.

Comment: I have had this before also, we required a clean run of an assembly matcher that ran under the main project directory.

Answer (score 4):

I will write it as an answer because it may be useful to others.
You can try to implement a check-in policy for unwanted file types 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364074(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364074%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
see under "Tracking Tasks and Enforcing Standards" header

Comment: Controlling these policies at the source control level rather than the IDE seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can control VB.NET support from Visual Studio, through [Unattended installation options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx).

You cannot completely prevent someone from using Windows Forms, or even VB.NET components.

They are a part of the core .NET platform (not visual studio), even removing template support from Visual Studio you can still add references to those assemblies.

This appears to be a *human* problem, not a *development* problem. If management has dictated certain development standards, and those standards are not being adhered to - that's something that management needs to handle. eg: Disciplinary action.